# does android NDK support socket epoll mode?

Tags: sockets, android-ndk

Im used the SFML socket module now, but it is only supported select module, I must create a thread for checking initiative. does android NDK support socket epoll mode? Where can find some codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at headers and libs, yes it does, but only starting from android-4b - not in android-3. Hardly a concern for a modern app though.